# How to Configure Clickpad?

Tags: xorg, configuration, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I am running xubuntu 13.10 on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon. It works very well, except the behaviour of my clickpad (touchpad where the buttons are built into the surface) makes it essentially unusable.

The default behaviour means that the whole area of the clickpad moves the mouse cursor, so that when I try and click anything, the mouse will move around slightly and I will miss my target.

After googling around, I saw suggestions suggesting that I should modify my `/etc/X11/xorg.d/50-synaptics` file ([man](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html)) so that the `AreaBottomEdge` option is set to the height of the button area on my clickpad.

This worked in that it prevented the mouse from moving when I touch the clickable area, but it now does not allow me to move the mouse with another finger while holding the left click button down, so I cannot do selections/dragging/etc.

What I am after is configuration settings (or a different driver) that will turn off mouse movement over the clickable area of the clickpad, but still allow me to move the mouse while another finger is resting on, or clicking down on the clickable area. Essentially I want to make the clickable areas act like real buttons.

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem with my E540, have you found a solution?

Comment: I managed to get something that tolerably works by replacing the default driver with xf86-input-mtrack. I had to spend a while changing the config to get something that was reasonable; even then, I haven't been able to get right-click working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` and adding this:

```
Option "SoftButtonAreas" "RBL RBR RBT RBB MBL MBR MBT MBB"
```

- `RBL` is Right Button Left,
- `RBR` is Right Button Right,
- `RBT` is Right Button Top,
- `RBB` is Right Button Bottom,
- `MBL` is Middle Button Left,
- `MBR` is Middle Button Right,
- `MBT` is Middle Button Top,
- `MBB` is Middle Button Bottom.

This defines the area of the clickpad where the touching clicks do not move the cursor. Maybe this didn't work way back then.

My ELAN1300:00 clickpad has these numbers where the middle button is from 40% to 60% of the touchpad width:

```
Option "SoftButtonAreas" "1924 0 1600 0 1379 1923 1600 0"
```

There can also be % values instead of touchpad coordinates:

```
Option "SoftButtonAreas" "1924 0 90% 0 1379 1923 90% 0"
```

This says the bottom 10% of the touchpad is reserved for the Soft Buttons and a touch will not move the cursor when beginning in that area. The `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` should show the final numbers used by the Xserver after interpreting the config file.